# Null parameter values in Npgsql 3.x

Tags: npgsql

My ORM does not know the type for a null `NpgsqlParameter` value at runtime. In Npgsql 2.x I could simply set

`parameter.value = DBNull.Value`

and this was all good. Now it seems I have to set a `DbType` too, but I don't know what the type's supposed to be, so I can't set it.

In 2.x it seems to be defaulting to String/text, but setting that explicitly in 3.x causes type exceptions.

What can I do, without having to modify all my SQL?

Is there a default `DbType` that will give the 2.x behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting NpgsqlDbType to `NpgsqlDbType.Unknown`?